# Use session, cache or global variables from Laravel console

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm processing transactions for many users, from the console/command. For each user/transaction processed, I need the user_id value accessible  in a package I've created.

What would be the best way to share the user_id value to the package? Session variable? Cache helper? A global variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use cache or config.

for config, create a global.php file in the config directory
and set your variables by `Config::set('global.user_id' , $user->id)` and for get that use `Config::get('global.user_id')`

for more information about config files read this useful [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-laravel-config-files)

also you can use redis database